# Checking if a geocoordinate point is land or ocean?

Tags: python, geolocation, matplotlib-basemap, insar

I got the corner geo coordinates from a xml product file of a Sentinel-1 GRD SAR image. When looping through the pixels of the image I wish to check whether it represents land or sea.

I figured I could calculate the corresponding longtitude and latitude by using the corner longtitudes and latitudes and do the check. Looking into `basemap` from `mpl_toolkits`, i found an attribute `.is_land(x, y)` but this require a map projection which slows it down, which I want to avoid.

Is there an efficient and fast way to check whether a longtitude and latitude is land or ocean in python 3.x?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  What have you tried?  What datasets have you got to perform your test?  Please [edit] your question to include details about your data and what you've tried.

Answer (score 9):

Basemap should fit your need. Its default projection is the raw use of (long, lat) for plotting/processing. In this case, it also takes projection='cyl' to conform with general uses. Here is the code to try:-

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
bm = Basemap()   # default: projection='cyl'
print bm.is_land(99.675, 13.104)  #True
print bm.is_land(100.539, 13.104)  #False
```

Edit

Basemap's default parameters:

```
projection='cyl', which takes raw (long, lat) in degrees as input
resolution='c', which is 'crude' version (options are 'i': intermediate; 'f': fine)
```

Warning: 'i' and 'f' resolutions take much longer time to process for results, use them only when you need more accurate result, and, appropriate lat-long extents should be specified when used.

Tips:
To speed up the process, lat-long extents should be specified with these options:

```
llcrnrlon: lower-left corner longitude
llcrnrlat: lower-left corner latitude
urcrnrlon: upper-right corner longitude
urcrnrlat: upper-right corner latitude, all in degrees
```

Answer (score 3):

There's one problem with Basemap.is_land(): it's really slow! To solve this, I've written a small package with a much faster function:
https://github.com/toddkarin/global-land-mask